# Move jquery ui to footer

Tags: footer

Am trying to move //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js
to the footer, i have used a function to do this but the results was to duplicate the js libray, one to header and the second to the footer.
Can anybody helps me and also tutors me more deeply how to move all js to footer please

Comment: Please read through the Codex page of **wp_enqueue_script()**. Look primarily into the $in_footer parameter. EDIT: Or just read the answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9775104/wp-enqueue-script-in-the-footer

Answer (score -1):

Ok i found alone the solution, the problem was that it is 'jquery-ui-core' and not 'jquery'.
Thank you a lot for the effort

**P.S:** In order not to open second similar thread, how do i find the theme js libraries and put them to footer, for example i have http://example.com/wp-content/themes/theme-name/js/dropdown.js and i want to move it to footer. If i use enqueue, it becomes double, one in header and one in footer. Basically i don't know where to go and find its handle name

Comment: Please don't ask question in answers, no one will pay attention or try to answer them properly. The short version is that you'll have to search through code for that.